# How can I save 3D array as a text file?

Tags: c#

I'd like to ask something about saving 3D array as a text file.

I have a code that use Monte Carlo simulation to simulate photon moving in medium.

This is the code for save 2D array data to text file.

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default))
{
    for (int i=0; i < simulate.ResultData.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < simulate.ResultData.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    sw.Write(simulate.ResultData[i,j] + "\t");
                }
                   sw.WriteLine();
               }
          }
```

I wonder if I can save 3D array as a text file by adding one more sentence like

```
for (int k=0; k < simulate.ResultData.GetLength(2); k++)
```

or I need to add another information in code.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try it? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I tried it. And it said System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

Answer (score 0):

You can "save" any object "in a text" file.  That's called `serialization`.  It doesn't matter if it's a 3D array, an array of objects each containing arrays of objects and objects containing arrays, etc.

A popular .NET serializing package is `NewtonSoft`.  Look for it in NuGet.

You can replace all your complex code above with:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(simulate));
```

This will work whatever type `simulate` is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that I can change all my code above with your one sentence code?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly true

Comment: Unless you need to conform to some other format, then yes, you can use that line of code to replace your entire code, and deserialization is just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<type[,,]>(json)`

Comment: I define JsonConvert by using and I changed my code with yours, but the data did not save as text file. The data file said it is not the form which is supported.

Comment: Total code for saving image and data as text file was 
public void SaveImg() 
{
 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
  imageBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
 
and then entire code that I mentioned in question. I changed code of my question to your code. After I run the program, there are no result image and only one jpg file which is not supported. I'm sorry to write complicated because this is comment space.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want the output file to be in text or jpg format.   Open the .jpg file in notepad and you should see the serialized text.  (you may need to select *.* in the file type box in notepad)

Comment: Oh, I could open very long one sentence-text file with Notepad. I'm not sure whether it is 3D array or not, it consists of a number of [ ] like [0, 0.12413431, 0, 0, 0.13414134],[0, 0, 0.314134, 0.34134,0]... I think I should try change the sentence. Thank you.